# How to build a distributed chat website on Azure without polling?

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

I need to make a website on Azure that has a simple chat feature-where one client can send a message to another waiting client

I'm not sure how to develop this without polling ("do you have a message for me")

I'm assuming the trick is to have one client send an async (blocking) call to the webserver,  then unblock the call when a new message arrives

... If I weren't in a distributed environment (one webserver) ,  this would be pretty easy to implement,  but when multiple frontend servers are involved I'm not sure the best way to coordinate

I'm flexible in pretty much all ways,  but it needs to run on Azure.   I can use sql azure, a Azure queue,  etc

Tips?

Comment: This is an interesting post, though it does not address your scenario exactly. But you can get an idea about using notification hub for the same
http://www.ageofmobility.com/2014/10/06/azurechatr-building-a-cross-platform-chat-app-for-windows-ios-android/

Answer (score 3):

SignalR with Sql Server Backplane is one viable solution that  can use a variety of techniques from Web sockets to server sent events to long polling to conventional polling automatically based on the clients capabilities.

Comment: Here is an tutorial as well i find from online http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites